# CSS Grid Navigaton Bar - How to properly add Button Separators?

Tags: css, flexbox, navigation, css-grid, nav

I'm designing a new css grid based navigation but I am wondering if there is a better way to implement a navigation button separator than a border-right.

I was thinking of implementing navigation separators based on the grid lines, but I don't know if that's possible and it may be frowned upon as a practice.

My design leaves a border-right on the right most element "name" which is not desirable. I tried using nth-child to disable it but that was not effective.

Is there a better way to separate buttons in a css grid nav bar than using a border property? I am primarily using css and html for navigation.

Any input greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto 1fr auto;
  padding: 0; 
  font: bold .95em Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #555555; 
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #161616;
  color: #CCC;
  padding: 10px 16px;  /*top&bott, right&left*/
}

nav a:hover {background: #2a2a2a;}
nav a.active {background: #2a2a2a;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="index">PROJECTS</a>
  <a href="cine">VIDEOS</a>
  <a href="photosets">PHOTOS</a>
  <a href="aboutme">ABOUT</a>
  <div></div>
  <a href="aboutme">NAME</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the individual links into a list. The nav element is a semantic container, but isn't great for display. And here's the updated CSS to move the last item to the end of the grid and remove the border.

```
nav ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto 1fr auto;
    padding: 0; 
    font: bold .95em Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #222222; 
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}
nav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #161616;
}
nav li a {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
nav li:last-child {
    justify-self: end;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Here's the updated markup.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="cine">VIDEOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="photosets">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme">NAME</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I would also change the links to use normal capitalization (Projects, Videos, etc.) and just make them all caps in CSS. `text-transform: uppercase`

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks a bunch for the input! I do like the way you used last-child and justify-self: end to target the last element. 
There is an issue though. The <a> link does not expand over the list element, it only expands over the text in the box. Ideally, I'd like to have each navigation button as a clickable link, including the space around the text inside each button. 
I found that a quick fix is to add padding: 10px 0px; to nav li and to change the padding on nav li a to padding: 10px 16px;

Comment: I edited my response to move the padding to the `a` and gave them a `display: inline-block` property. This also improves the hover state and more closely matches your desired look.

Comment: I would also suggest adding `border-right: none` to `nav li:nth-child(4)` for a consistent look.